# ASP.NET Connection string in Docker

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, postgresql, docker

So, i am trying to connect to my postgres database that is set up in docker.

But i wanted to have a more secure connection string, like a environment variable that will not go to github since this application i want to deploy to azure.

I already tried putting this in my compose, but keep saying that the host can't be null

```
environment:
      - "ConnectionStrings__DbContext=User ID=postgres;Password=postgres;Host=app_db;Port=5433;Database=asp;Pooling=true;"
```

this is my app settings

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DbContext": "User ID=postgres;Password=postgres;Host=localhost;Port=5433;Database=asp;Pooling=true;"
  }
}
```

and this is my Program.cs

```
options.UseNpgsql(
    builder.Configuration["ConnectionStrings:DbContext"]
));
```

Comment: And have you connected into a shell in your docker container and checked that the env var is suitably set? (And have you configured your Config provider so that it uses environment variables as a source of config info? It's all well and good that you might have got the env var set correctly, but if you need to have a line like `.AddEnvironmentVariables...` on your config builder - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-8.0)

Comment: By the way,consider using User Secrets so you don't end up committing that conn str to source control. User Secrets are just like app settings, but theyre buried in your personal documents folders on your hard disk and well out of the way of accidental commit. You can access the facility by right clicking the project in the solution explorer and choosing "manage user secrets" near the "manage nuget packages" menu item

Comment: (And if youre getting "host cannot be null", perhaps the call to get the conn str is returning null for the whole string, so there is nothing to parse - the config system doesn't necessarily throw any exception when there is no config item by a particular name, it just returns a null string which then causes some problem elsewhere. Personally I use a snippet like `private static string GetConfig(string name) => _config[name] is string x && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x) ? x : throw new ArgumentNullException(name, $"The configuration is missing a key:value pair with a key of '{name}'");` to detect)